# Symfony Doctrine - InheritanceType SINGLE_TABLE is not changing target Entity when Dicscriminator changes but not Id

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, single-table-inheritance

I'm trying to handle a legacy database with doctrine.
There is many fields in different tables that are codes which refer to a unique code table CHOIXCOD. This table relies on two keys. The key (CC_CODE) that corresponds to the value in the linked fields, and a type code (CC_TYPE) identifying which field the first key is targeting.

So i used Doctrine Inheritance on an abstract entity targeting this code table, and created as many children entities as there is difference types.
What i understand is that Doctrine will make snippets of CHOIXCOD on the CC_TYPE field, and in each snippet, CC_CODE will be the key column.

But, when all $ccCode are differents all works fine, but, in one table having multiple references to CHOIXCOD, if two fields referencing CC_CODE have the same value, Doctrine will give them the same CC_TYPE value, resulting in targeting the wrong entity, crash, 500 error, project being late, me being fired.

So here is the mother entity.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="CHOIXCOD")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="CC_TYPE", type="string", length=3)
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"PHV" = "Phasevocale",
 *                        "TMS" = "Typemessage",
 *                        "PRI" = "Priorite",
 *                        "ZEL" = "Etatlivraison",
 *                        "ZEM" = "Etatmessage",
 *                        "ZOR" = "Originems"})
 */

abstract class Choixcod
{

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CC_CODE", type="string", length=3, nullable=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $ccCode;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CC_LIBELLE", type="string", length=105, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $ccLibelle;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CC_ABREGE", type="string", length=17, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $ccAbrege;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CC_LIBRE", type="string", length=70, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $ccLibre;
```

And all the children are like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Etatmessage extends Choixcod{}
```

They are then used in other entities following a ManyToOne relation

```
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Etatmessage")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ZMS_ETATMESSAGE", referencedColumnName="CC_CODE")
     * @ToNull(primaryKey="ccCode")
     */
    private $zmsEtatmessage;
```

The @ToNull annotation is one we wrote to handle the empty or full of spaces foreign keys). I tried to removed them, that doesn't change anything.

Any idea welcome.

Comment: `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Etatmessage")` (last code sample) already explicitly tells the type of the target entity, no? Don't know, if changing that will actually work, though ... if the children are empty though, you might want to rethink if having multiple classes isn't too hard, and using a `getType()` or something would be easier, that way you wouldn't have to handle the mind bend that is inheritance mapping.

Comment: Actually it's not that hard and it works pretty well, according to Doctrine documentation it's an efficient strategy. I suppose this is only a cache problem, Doctrine must assume that he knows this id for this instanceof [motherclass] no need to request the database let's load it. Something like this, approximatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after struggling with that problem for a while, I understood that Doctrine stores a two dimensions array in order to request joins (1-entity joined, 2-id of entity instance). I suppose the aim is to limit the number of request done for a yet known instance.

In our case, inheritance, the first dimension of the array is named with the extended entity so as I had the same ids for the same first dimension name that was messed up from the beginning. Setting the discriminator as `@Id` could have solved this problem but Doctrine does not automatically set the discriminator value in object, throwing an id missing exception.

So the solution I kept is to put an annotation on foreign key that specifies discriminator value this foreign key corresponds to. When encountered in doctrine `postLoad` event, I request the database on foreign key value (the primary key corresponding being `CC_CODE`) and discriminator (the value of `CC_TYPE`) in annotation, and put it into an another field.